# Bitnami Wapp stack: In the installation wizard, PhpPgAdmin is grayed out and I cannot be selected to enable it. Is there away around this?

Tags: stack, bitnami, phppgadmin

I am trying to use the phppgAdmin with the Bitnami Wapp Stack installer on a Windows 10 virtual machine. The installer seemed to install just fine except the option to include phppgadmin was grayed out and there was no way to enable it. Does anyone know of a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am resolving my own question here. I have downloaded another version that phpPGAdmin is enabled for wappstack-7.4.27-0.  Downloaded and everything worked perfectly. Still, if there is another option for the above version I would like to know the solution or understand why it is disabled for the higher version of wappstack-8.x.xx-x.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami wapp stack ships with PHP version 8+.

It seems there is no PHP 8+ supported version of phppgadmin yet, see release on github: https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/releases.